# error routeProvider not defined also with ngRoute used and angular-route.js included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

i'am trying to make work partials and roue with not success.

I have errors in console that says me several things :

1/ $routeProvider said not defined in todolist.js while ngRoute is declared in module and angular-route.js requested
2/ It says me in controller.js that it missed formal parameter at line 4 (function line)

todolist.js

```
var todoList = angular.module('todoList',['ngRoute','todoListController']);

todoList.config([$routeProvider,function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/inbox',{
            templateUrl:'partials/inbox.html',
            controller: 'todoCtrl'
        })
        .when('/today',{
            templateUrl:'partials/today.html',
            controller: 'todoCtrl'
        })
        .otherwhise({
            redirectTo: '/inbox'
        })
}])
```

controller.js

```
var todoListController= angular.module('todoListController', []);

todoListController.controller('todoCtrl',['$scope',
    function ('$scope') {
        var todos = $scope.todos = [];
        $scope.addTodo = function () {
            var newTodo = $scope.newTodo.trim();
            if (!newTodo.length) {
                return;
            }
            todos.push({
                title: newTodo,
                completed: false
            });
            $scope.newTodo = '';
        };
        $scope.removeTodo = function (todo) {
            todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todo), 1);
        };
        $scope.markAll = function (completed) {
            todos.forEach(function (todo) {
                todo.completed = !completed;
            });
        };
        $scope.clearCompletedTodos = function () {
            $scope.todos = todos = todos.filter(function (todo) {
                return !todo.completed;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" ng-app="todoList">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
              <div class="container-fluid" >
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pense-bête</a>
                </div>
                 <div class="navbar navbar-right" id="myNavbar" >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" ng-click="clearCompletedTodos()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" ng-click="clearCompletedTodos()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" ng-click="clearCompletedTodos()">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </button></li>                            
                    </ul>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row">

        </div>    
        <div class="row" id="menu">
            <div class="col-sm-3 cold-md-2" id="left-menu">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox">
                    </span> Boite de réception</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Aujourd'hui</a></li>               
                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Cette semaine</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"></i> Important </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></span>
                        Repas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                        Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
                        Perso</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                        Nouvelle liste</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9 cold-md-10" id='main-view' ng-controller="todoCtrl" >
                <form id="todo-form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
                    <input id="new-todo" placeholder="Que voulez-vous noter ?" ng-model="newTodo" />
                </form>
                <div class="view" ng-view>

                </div>


            </div>

        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/todolist.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

inbox.html

```
        <article ng-show="todos.length">
            <ul id="todo-list">
                <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" ng-class="{completed: todo.completed}">
                    <div class="view">
                        <input class="mark" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.completed" />
                        <span>{{todo.title}}</span>

                        <span class="close" ng-click="removeTodo(todo)">x</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <input id="mark-all" type="checkbox" ng-model="allChecked" ng-click="markAll(allChecked)" />
                <label class="btn btn-info" for="mark-all">Tout cocher</label>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="clearCompletedTodos()">Supprimer les tâches cochées</button>
            </div>
        </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

When explicitly naming dependencies (as you are doing), you need to pass the actual named dependencies as a string first, and then a named parameter to your function.

```
todoList.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){}]);
```

Here the `$routeProvider` dependency must be named explicitly as a string, and is then passed to the function as the first parameter. Using this method allows for code minification without breaking, as Angular no longer relies on the parameter to be named as an exact dependency (amongst other benefits).

Similar to above, your second error is because you have a string as a function parameter, when it should be a variable name.

```
todoListController.controller('todoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);
```

Also you need to tell your Angular module to use the controller, instead of creating a new module and placing the controller onto that. This way your `todoList` module knows about the `todoListController`

```
var todoListController= angular.module('todoListController', []);
```

Should become

```
var todoListController= angular.module('todoList');
```

Comment: Tank you for the explanation, but what should it be for todolist.config line ?

Comment: The config line I provided above should fix your error.